# Python establishing connection with UDP BitTorrent tracker

Tags: python, udp, bittorrent, magnet-uri

I'm learning how to establish connection with a `udp` tracker to send connections and receive a response. However, I am not sure why I am not receiving a connection response.

The torrent that I am trying to obtain the files from is located [here](http://academictorrents.com/details/5daa22057577521a378b71e0f0de6a934bd5c2ea)

```
# It produces this magnet link. 
mag_link = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5daa22057577521a378b71e0f0de6a934bd5c2ea&tr=http%3A%2F%2Facademictorrents.com%2Fannounce.php&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce'
```

After which, I use `urllib.parse` to parse the link to obtain elements such as`xt`, `tr`, `dn`, etc.

```
from urllib import parse
processed_mag_link = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(mag_link).query)
```

I have gone through some documentations on `bit torrent protocols` and `udp connections` and got the below code. Would really appreciate if you can share with me why I am unable to obtain a connection response from the tracker.

```
import random
import socket
import struct
from urllib import parse
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def magnet_link_decode(mag_link):
    # Parsing of mag_link
    processed_mag_link = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(mag_link).query)
    # Renaming of mag_link
    processed_mag_link = {
        'exact_topic': processed_mag_link.get('xt'),
        'display_name': processed_mag_link.get('dn'),
        'tracker_name': processed_mag_link.get('tr')
    }
    print(processed_mag_link['tracker_name'])
    return processed_mag_link


def announce_udp(processed_nag_link):
    trackers = magnet_link_decode(processed_nag_link)['tracker_name']

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.settimeout(5)

    for tracker in trackers:
        tracker = urlparse(tracker)
        try:
            if tracker.scheme == 'udp':
                print('connecting to: ', tracker.hostname)
                connection = (socket.gethostbyname(tracker.hostname), tracker.port)
                request, transaction_id = udp_create_connection_request()
                sock.sendto(request, connection)
                buffer = sock.recvfrom(1048)[0]
                connection_id = udp_parse_connection_response(buffer, transaction_id)
                print(connection_id)
            elif tracker.scheme == 'http':
                pass  # do nothing for now

        except socket.gaierror:
            print('Connection to: {err} failed..'.format(err=tracker.hostname))
        except socket.timeout:
            pass  


def udp_parse_connection_response(buf, sent_transaction_id):

    print('connecting')
    if len(buf) < 16:
        raise RuntimeError("Wrong response length getting connection id: %s" % len(buf))
    action = struct.unpack_from("!i", buf)[0]  # first 4 bytes is action

    res_transaction_id = struct.unpack_from("!i", buf, 4)[0]  # next 4 bytes is transaction id
    if res_transaction_id != sent_transaction_id:
        raise RuntimeError("Transaction ID doesnt match in connection response! Expected %s, got %s"
                       % (sent_transaction_id, res_transaction_id))

    if action == 0x0:
        connection_id = struct.unpack_from("!q", buf, 8)[0]  # unpack 8 bytes from byte 8, should be the connection_id
        return connection_id
    elif action == 0x3:
        error = struct.unpack_from("!s", buf, 8)
        raise RuntimeError("Error while trying to get a connection response: %s" % error)


def udp_create_connection_request():
    connection_id = 0x41727101980  # default connection id
    action = 0x0  # action (0 = give me a new connection id)
    transaction_id = int(random.randrange(0, 255))
    print("Transaction ID :", transaction_id)
    buffer = struct.pack("!q", connection_id)  # first 8 bytes is connection id
    buffer += struct.pack("!i", action)  # next 4 bytes is action
    buffer += struct.pack("!i", transaction_id)  # next 4 bytes is transaction id

    return buffer, transaction_id
```

For the first part, `magnet_link_decode` is essentially parsing of the magnet link to obtain the `info_hash` as well as the trackers.

The next part of `announce_udp` is to see if i can connect and get a response returned from the tracker. I'm not exactly sure if this is correct, but it doesnt seem to be able to receive anything from the code `buffer = sock.recvfrom(1048)[0]`

Comment: What would help us help you is a single, runnable script which goes from the very first `import` statement (vs the code you've posted now which has *comments* saying what to import!), to the first part that fails, with an explanation of what the results are and what you expect to be different.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've edited as you have mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know whether the trackers support udp announces? Have you compared with a working bittorrent client? Try comparing a working and your own announce with wireshark.

Comment: @the8472 sorry but could you please explain more about "whether the trackers support udp announces"? I don't quite get what you mean by this.

Comment: not all trackers support BEP 15. Have you actually checked whether it supports it or only http announces?

Comment: Thanks for your response. i've not checked it actually! let me take a look at it. I'm still really new about udp and BEPs.